# Is the Harry Keller character in Andrew Macdonald's racist novel "Hunter" a follower of Rudolf Steiner?

Tags: andrew-macdonald, hunter

In the racist novel *Hunter* (1989), written by United States neo-Nazi William Luther Pierce under the pseudonym Andrew Macdonald, the character Harry Keller opines in Chapter 30 as follows (emphasis added):

> "*Our aim is to keep the race from going down the drain, if we can. More than that, it's to get the race back on an upward path again, to get it back to work **preparing the way for a higher race to come** (....)*"
>
> "*We identify with our race, with an idealization of our race - more than that, with the process of which our race is the principal agent, the **process** of **higher organization**, the process which is the active principle of God.*"

The idea of an Aryan race evolving into a higher future race appears in the work of "theosophist" Helena Blavatsky and is an important part of the ideology of the "anthroposophist" Rudolf Steiner. Note that the emergence of a new race is different from the strengthening of an existing supposedly "higher" race that was supported by Cambridge-educated eugenicists Francis Galton and Karl Pearson, even when the "higher" one causes the "lower" one to become "extinct", as Galton advocated. Keller specifically talks of a "path", of a divine "process" of "higher organization", and of preparing the way for a future "higher race" which is not simply an existing race made stronger or that has "extinguished" "lower" races.

Is Keller a follower of Rudolf Steiner? If not, is Macdonald giving him some other specific and recognisable strand of racist ideology?